# How do I filter a custom post type loop by a field?

Tags: custom-post-types, php, custom-field, loop, filters

OK, very simple task, I'm just not good at PHP.

I have a page where I want to list some staff using a styled list. Here is the page all working fine, I just need to divide the results - http://www.themontessoripeople.co.uk/montesori/?post_type=people

I downloaded a "custom content type" plugin and added the content type of "people" and added the appropriate fields. Now I want to filter the posts I have added by the custom field called "hierarchy".

Here is how I want the page to display:

[image]

Notice in the image I have headings for each group of posts filtered by the room. The custom field "hierarchy" contains the room variables of either "management", "babies_room" and "toddlers_room".

How do I amend the code below to filter the posts by the value held within `<?php print_custom_field('hierarchy'); ?>` ?

```
<?php $col = 1; ?>      
    <?php if (have_posts()) : ?>        
        <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>         
            <?php if ($col == 1) echo "<div class=\"row\">"; ?>

                <div class="post col<?php echo $col;?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">

                            <div class="people-spacer">

                                <div class="people"><a class="animate" >
                                <div class="bio">
                                <p class="titles"><?php the_title(); ?><br/>
                                <span class="job"> <?php print_custom_field('job'); ?></span> </p><br />
                                </div>
                                <img src="<?php print_custom_field('staff_image:to_image_src'); ?>" width="160" height="160" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>-image" />
                                </div>
                                <div class="people-link-edit"><?php edit_post_link('Edit Post', ''); ?></div>
                            </div>
                </div>

            <?php if ($col == 1) echo "</div>"; (($col==1) ? $col=2 : $col=2); ?>   
        <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Something like this should work:

```
meta_key=hierarchy&meta_value=management
```

This should be added into the query_posts function, that is not shown in your code block, but should come before it.